# Android React Native Height 0 on Animated.View

Tags: android, react-native

We toggle an `Animated.View`'s height between full height and 0. When we animate the view to height of 0 it automatically re-opens, changing the value to minimize to 1 fixes it but is visible and not desired.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.visible !== nextProps.visible) {
    const newHeight = nextProps.visible ? viewportHeight(100) : 0;
    Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
      duration: 250,
      toValue: newHeight,
    });

    Animated.timing(this.state.searchBarHeight, {
      duration: 150,
      toValue: nextProps.visible ? 56 : 0,
    }).start();

    Animated.timing(this.state.iconBarHeight, {
      duration: 150,
      toValue: nextProps.visible ? 56 : 0,
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you add the `collapsible` prop to the View (which is specific to Android) it will prevent the optimization code from potentially removing the view from the hierarchy.